# How to break Latex Long Table at the start of merged rows?

Tags: longtable

I am using the following code to create a long table-

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{lllllll}
\caption{Random Data}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
Instance   No. & Concept No. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{7}{c}%
{{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
Instance   No. & Concept No. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\endhead
%
\multirow{5}{*}{1-1} & Name & A & B & C & D & E \\
 & a & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 & b & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 6 \\
 & x & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} \\
 & y & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} \\
\multirow{5}{*}{1-2} & Name & A & B & C & D &  \\
 & a & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 &  \\
 & b & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &  \\
 & x & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} &  \\
 & y & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} &  \\
\multirow{5}{*}{1-3} & Name & A & B & C & D &  \\
 & a & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 &  \\
 & b & 7 & 7 & 8 & 9 &  \\
 & x & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} &  \\
 & y & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & {[}1,1{]} & 
\end{longtable}
```

However, sometimes, the table breaks in the middle of a merged row to run into the next page. How can I prevent breaking at the merged rows? I want the table to break before the start of the merged row.

Comment: use `\\ \newpage` to force a break and `\\*` to prevent one.

Comment: I do not want force breaking. Is there any way to do it adaptively?

Comment: as I say, use `\\*` for lines that should not page break (eg any rows spanned by multirow)

Comment: Sorry, I am a new user of Latex. Can you please show me in the code where should I use those?

Comment: use `\\*`  where you have used `\\ `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late ...

Using `longtable` your table code should be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{longtable, multirow} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{longtable}[c]{lllllll}
\caption{Random Data}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
    \toprule
Instance   No. & Concept No. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
%
\caption[]{Random Data} \\
    \toprule
Instance   No. & Concept No. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape Continued on next page}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%
\multirow{5}{*}{1-1} 
    & Name & A & B & C & D & E \\*
    & a & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\*
    & b & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 6 \\*
    & x & [1,1] & {[}1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] \\*
    & y & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] \\
\multirow{5}{*}{1-2}
    & Name & A & B & C & D &  \\*
    & a & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 &  \\*
    & b & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &  \\*
    & x & [1,1{]} & [1,1{]} & [1,1{]} & [1,1] &  \\*
    & y & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] &  \\
\multirow{5}{*}{1-3}
    & Name & A & B & C & D &  \\*
    & a & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 &  \\*
    & b & 7 & 7 & 8 & 9 &  \\*
    & x & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] &  \\*
    & y & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] &  \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

As You can see, I a wee bit change table design that looks a bit nice :-). However, I would consider to use `tabularray` package. By its table environment `longtblr` table code is quite shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
      \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachfive}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{5}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
    \ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Random Data},
  label = {tab:my-table}
                ]{colspec={ Q[c,m,wd=4em] Q[c,m,wd=3em] *{6}{c} },
                  cell{2,7,12}{1} = {r=5}{m},
                  row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
                  row{2} = {abovesep=2pt},   row{Z} = {belowsep=2pt},
                  row{eachfive} = {belowsep=1ex},
                  rowhead  = 1
                 }
    \toprule
Instance   No. & Concept No. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \midrule
1-1 & Name & A & B & C & D & E                      \\*
    \midrule
    & a & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2                         \\*
    & b & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 6                         \\*
    & x & [1,1] & {[}1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1]   \\*
    & y & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1]     \\
%
1-2 & Name & A & B & C & D &                        \\*
    \midrule
    & a & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 &                           \\*
    & b & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &                           \\*
    & x & [1,1{]} & [1,1{]} & [1,1{]} & [1,1] &     \\*
    & y & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] &           \\
%
1-3 & Name & A & B & C & D &                        \\*
    \midrule
    & a & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 &                           \\*
    & b & 7 & 7 & 8 & 9 &                           \\*
    & x & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] &           \\*
    & y & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] & [1,1] &           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

In above MWE I a little bit change table style:

[image]

ble code is quite shorter: